# How do I get the Wubi installer to use a pre-downloaded ISO?

Tags: 10.04, windows

I have this iso file `ubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso` and then I downloaded the corresponding wubi installer for this version. Place them inside the same directory in Windows, but instead of making use of the iso file it ignores it and goes ahead with downloading another one. What am I supposed to do? Did I download the wrong version of iso file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Note: *wubi.exe* will say "downloading files" for a short time **even if** it is using the pre-downloaded ISO. Please follow the steps below and try again.
>
> **Quick links to *wubi.exe* and appropriate ISOs**:
>
> - 10.04.4 *Lucid* LTS: [wubi.exe](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/wubi.exe), [32-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-i386.iso), [64-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso)
> - 11.10 *Oneiric:* [wubi.exe](http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/wubi.exe), [32-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-i386.iso), [64-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/ubuntu-11.10-desktop-amd64.iso)
> - 12.04 *Precise* LTS: [wubi.exe](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe), [32-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso), [64-bit ISO](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso)

#### Requirements to use an existing ISO:

In general, [here are the requirements to use a pre-downloaded ISO with Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_use_a_manually_downloaded_ISO.3F) along with my recommendations for a successful install:

- You must download **the desktop CD** version of the ISO and **place it in the same directory/folder as *wubi.exe*** before running `wubi.exe`

  - Get **both** *wubi.exe* and the ISO from the same server folder, e.g. `http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/`
  - I *highly recommend* creating a new folder with but two files in it: `wubi.exe` and the ISO
  - The ISO can be 32-bit (i386) or 64-bit (amd64); Wubi will happily install whichever it finds in its folder.
- Alternate/server ISOs are not supported
- DVD ISOs are not supported *except* for Edubuntu

**Illustration of the misleading "downloading/retrieving" issue:**

[image]