# Why did Wubi install Gnome when I gave it the Xubuntu ISO?

Tags: installation, wubi, xubuntu

I downloaded the Xubuntu ISO file from the official site. But after installing it through the wubi installer I still got gnome interface instead of Xfce. What's gone wrong? What should I do? I double checked the file.

Answer (score 3):

The Wubi installer ignored your ISO, and simply downloaded and installed regular Ubuntu instead.

Uninstall Wubi, and try again. Follow the instructions in this answer on how to get `wubi.exe` to use your pre-downloaded ISO:

> [How do I get the Wubi installer to use a pre-downloaded ISO?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159524/how-do-i-get-the-wubi-installer-to-use-a-pre-downloaded-iso/159533#159533)

Finally, to be safe, physically disconnect your Ethernet cable OR disable wireless (turn switch off, etc.) before you press the Install Button on Wubi.