# Wubi downloads ISO even though it's already there

Tags: system-installation, wubi, iso

I am trying to install Ubuntu on Windows 8. My system does not have the SecureBoot and UEFI option. I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 ISO from the website. It contains `wubi.exe`, but when I run Wubi it starts downloading the Ubuntu ISO again.

I tried the option of putting the ISO and `wubi.exe` in an empty folder and then running it, but it still downloads a new ISO. Why can't it use the ISO I already have?

Comment: What does the logfile say? Check in `%TEMP%\wubi-12.04.2-rev272.log` or [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) the entire file and post the link here so we can see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the Wubi installer to use a pre-downloaded ISO?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159524/how-do-i-get-the-wubi-installer-to-use-a-pre-downloaded-iso)

Answer (score 2):

Most possibly you have downloaded (the default downlaod) a 32 bit ISO where as your machine support 64bit. So wubi detects it and tries to download 64bit ubuntu ISO.

To force using 32bit, open the folder where you stored `wubi.exe` and ISO. Now right click while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click on `Open a command window here`

Now execute Wubi.exe with parameter `--32bit`, the command should be like `Wubi.exe --32bit`

Few more points for troubleshooting:

- Make sure you are not using dvd/ alternative ISO. Those are not supported by wubi.
- ISO not corrupt.
- Download wubi from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/wubi.exe
- 5GB free space is required.

More FAQs and details : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide