# Use WUBI to install downloaded ISO

Tags: wubi, system-installation

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 to my Windows machine, because I would like to install it on several similar machines, however, when I extracted the ISO and ran WUBI, it made me download Ubuntu again. Any ways around this?

Comment: have you tried mounting the disc image take a look at  this as well http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the Wubi installer to use a pre-downloaded ISO?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/159524/how-do-i-get-the-wubi-installer-to-use-a-pre-downloaded-iso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't extract the ISO. Save it in the same folder as `wubi.exe` and run Wubi and it will use the ISO.

Make sure you have the right version of `wubi.exe`. Either copy it from the ISO or download it from the same place you got the ISO i.e. http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Also, you can run it from a mounted ISO (not extracted) as long as you use the `--force-wubi` option (i.e. run `wubi.exe --force-wubi`)